# How to drop Enter, when I'm using Scanner?

Tags: java.util.scanner, enter

I want to write a program where you don't need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, when I'm using Scanner. Is there any way to avoid that? It supposed to be very simple program, but every time I am write something, I have to press enter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a scanner like

```
Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String scanInfo = userInputScanner.nextLine();
```

Then you need to press <kbd>enter</kbd> after because [the docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) the method:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.
>
> Since *this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator*, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present."

Essentially, by pressing enter you are telling the computer your input is done

If you need something that can scan information without pressing enter, you can scan a text file like this:

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";                             
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
```

Instead of input, you can use a txt file as well

Note: in the string input example, you would likely want to use a delimiter (for instance separating the String input at instances of white space)

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(Character.isWhitespace);
```

Personally, I like using txt files because with each line in the file I can use `.hasNext()` to get the data.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO, and good job writing a nice answer to an old question